# How to store texture uniforms in the state of the program?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, state, uniform

I already learned that uniform values are stored in the state of the shader program.

```
// GLSL code
uniform mat4 projection;

// C++ code
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, pointer);
```

But that seems to not apply for texture uniforms since they are bound by the number of a texture slot instead of their id.

```
// GLSL code
uniform sampler2D albedo;

// C++ code
int slot = 3;
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + slot);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "albedo");
glUniform1i(location, slot);
```

Is there a way to bind a texture id to a `sampler2D` uniform of a shader? This way I would not have to bind all textures manually for each pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to bind a texture id to a sampler2D uniform of a shader?

No, not really, because samplers access texture units, not texture objects. However NVidia's Kepler GPUs can use bindless textures, available to OpenGL as a vendor specific extension, which practically implement what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I simplify the process using `layout(location = 3)` at least?

Comment: Well, if all that you desire is, that you can write `glUniform1i(3, texture_unit_to_use);` then yes.

Comment: Ok, I realized that this is another matter.

Comment: @sharethis: "*Can I simplify the process using layout(location = 3) at least?*" If you have a GL 4.2 implementation or hardware that supports [shading_language_420pack](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_420pack.txt), yes. Only it's `binding`, not `location`.